# IO::Socket::INET "send: Cannot determine peer address"

Tags: perl, sockets

I have this Perl code snippet:

```
my $serverSocket = new IO::Socket::INET(
    LocalPort  => 53,
    Proto      => 'udp',
    ReuseAddr  => 1,
) or Error("Could't open server socket.");
print "Server started.\n";
my $clientQuery;
while (1) {
    $serverSocket->recv($clientQuery, 1024, 0);
    my $clientQueryParsed = IncomingDNSPacket::parseDNSPacket($clientQuery);
    my @questions = @{ $clientQueryParsed->{questions} };
    my @answers = map {getAnswer($_, $forwarder)} @questions;
    my $errorCode = @answers == 0 ? 3 : '';
    my $clientResponseParsed = {
        errorCode     => $errorCode,
        id            => $clientQueryParsed->{id},
        questions     => \@questions,
        answerRRs     => \@answers,
        additionalRRs => [],
        authorityRRs  => [],
    };
    my $clientResponse = OutgoingDNSPacket::makeAnswer(%$clientResponseParsed);
    $serverSocket->send($clientResponse, 0);
}
```

Sometimes `$serverSocket->send($clientResponse, 0);` returns this error: `send: Cannot determine peer address`. I tried to google it and found that this situation can be if socket was closed by remote host. But this is not TCP, this is UDP. Why do I get this error?

**EDIT:** Here's code of `getAnswer`:

```
sub getAnswer {
    my $question = shift;
    my $forwarder = shift;
    my @answer;
    @answer = $cache -> get($question);
    if (@answer == 0) {
        my $forwarderPacket = getAnswerFromForwarder($question);
        $cache -> add ($forwarderPacket);
        @answer = $cache -> get($question);
    }
    return @answer;
}

sub getAnswerFromForwarder {
    my $question = shift;
    my $forwQuery = OutgoingDNSPacket::makeQuestion(id => 0, questions => [$question]);
    my $forwSock = new IO::Socket::INET (
            PeerAddr => $forwarder,
            PeerPort => 53,
            Proto => 'udp'
        ) or Error("Couldn't create forwarder socket");
    $forwSock -> send($forwQuery, 0);
    my $select = new IO::Select;
    $select -> add ($forwSock);
    my @socks = $select -> can_read(2);
    if (@socks > 0) {
        my $forwAnswer;
        $forwSock -> recv($forwAnswer, 1024, 0);
        my $forwUnpacked = IncomingDNSPacket::parseDNSPacket($forwAnswer);
        return $forwUnpacked;
    } else {
        return {
            errorCode => 3,
            questions => [],
            answerRRs => [],
            authorityRRs => [],
            additionalRRs => []
            };
    }
}
```

`$forwSock`'s `send` can be unsuccessful. And if it is unsuccessful, I can't send anything from `$serverSocket`. Why?

Comment: The server processes one command per connection (after which $serverSocket gets destroyed). So the client can't send a second command w/o reconnecting (which is done in ->new() when you specify a PeerAddr).

Comment: @ChankeyPathak PeerAddr? And why doesn't this bug always appear? Sometimes it's OK, but it shouldn't be okay, if socket is destroyed.

Comment: Tcpdump or wireshark to see what's really going on.

Comment: Regarding your edit, how do you know that the other `send` is unsuccessful?  Why do you think it has bearing on your original question?

Comment: @pilcrow There can be situation I send packet to the closed port form `$forwSock`.

Comment: @user23791, sorry that's not clear enough for me. In any case the two sockets' problems should be unrelated unless there's buggy logic between them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Your problem is that you are not handling `$udpSocket->recv(...)` errors, and this is confounding your later `send`.

Most likely the `recv` fails with ECONNREFUSED.  You want to ignore this error and try again, and do the same for the `send` call, too.

**Longer Answer**

To clarify, your call to `send` does not *return* the error "Cannot determine peer address" — it [`croak`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html)s with that message.

IO::Socket remembers the remote peer address after a successful call to `$io_socket->recv()`.  This peer is the implicit destination for the next call to `$io_socket->send()`.  An *unsuccessful* `recv`, however, leaves no peer address available, and the following `send` simply `croak`s for want of a destination.

(Your code doesn't choke because the `recv` buffer, `$clientQuery`, is unmodified after a failed `recv`.  You are processing the previously `recv`d packet again.)

Now, *because this is UDP*, the underlying error probably pertains to a previous failed `send`.  Most likely you sent a datagram, an ICMP "dest unreach" came back sometime later, and the subsequent `send`/`recv` call on the socket reports this as ECONNREFUSED.

**Pseudocoded Answer**

```
use Errno;    # for %!
#use caution; this is untested and not thoroughly thought through

while (1) {
  my $ok = $udpSocket->recv($buf, $len, 0);
  if (! $ok) {
    redo if $!{ECONNREFUSED};  # Error from a previous UDP send
    die "recv: $!\n";
  }

  ...

  do {
    $ok = $udpSocket->send($buf, 0);
  } while (! $ok and $!{ECONNREFUSED});
}
```

Comment: But can I specify address and port I need to send packet in `$socket -> send` call?

Comment: @user23791, re: send with a destination, yes, but that won't matter if you don't have a peer to send it to.